# Typescript complex query format

Tags: typescript

I've got a method with this signature:

```
data: QueryDto<UmAccountPrivateSearchField>
```

The problem is I don't know how to type

filter (not using null) and sort

Put the case to search a user by id or email

### Models

```
export enum UmAccountPrivateSearchField { 
    UserId = "UserId" 
};

export type QueryDto<T> = {     
    offset: number; 
    max: number; 
    filter: FilterDto<T>| null; 
    sort:     OrderByDto<T>[] 
};

export type FilterDto<T> = 
 | { Eq: [T, string] } 
 | { GE: [T, string] } 
 | { GT: [T, string] } 
 | { LE: [T, string] } 
 | { LT: [T, string] };

export type OrderByDto<T> = [T, OrderBy];

export enum OrderBy { ASC = "ASC", DESC = "DESC", DEFAULT = "DEFAULT" };
```

How is the actual query?

```
const data = {  
 offset: 0, 
 max: 1, 
 filter:// what's here not using null,  
 sort:// what's here
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If T is {}, data will be something like this:

```
const data: QueryDto<{}> = {
  offset: 0,
  max: 1,
  filter: { Eq: [{}, 'name'] },
  sort: [[{}, OrderBy.ASC]]
}
```

**Updated with UmAccountPrivateSearchField**

```
const data: QueryDto<UmAccountPrivateSearchField> = {
  offset: 0,
  max: 1,
  filter: { Eq: [UmAccountPrivateSearchField.UserId, 'name'] },
  sort: [[UmAccountPrivateSearchField.UserId, OrderBy.ASC]]
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply but could you give me an example with UmAccountPrivateSearchField as T please?

Comment: @user3887366 check the example :)